# How to find out maximum offset value for a particular kafka topic in CDH kerborised cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, kerberos, offset, cloudera-cdh

I have a CDH cluster of 41 nodes using Kerberos, 28 of which have Kafka installed.

I want to find out the maximum offset value for a particular Kafka Topic.

I am using the below command, but it is not working. 
(Note: the option to use `kafka-run-class.sh` is not working for CDH)

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh  \ 
--command-config /home/username/client.properties \
--group examplehost1:9092,examplehost2:9092,<many more>, examplehost41:9092 \
--topic roc-parse-7485 \
--zookeeper examplezookeperhost1:2181,examplezookeperhost2:2181,examplezookeperhost3:2181
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably because you configured your brokers in the `group` parameter. `--group` should be the group name you wish to track.

Nevertheless, you can use GetOffsetShell - it gives you the latest offset for each topic partition.
You can find more info here: [GetOffsetShell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell)
You should use it like this:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell  --broker-list BROKER_LISTS --partitions 
 PARTITIONS_LIST --topic TOPIC_NAME
```

In your case:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell  --broker-list rahdpapp00.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpapp01.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpapp02.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpapp03.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpapp04.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpapp05.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpapp06.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpapp07.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp00.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp01.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp02.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp03.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp04.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp05.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp06.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp07.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp08.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp09.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp10.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp11.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp12.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpdtp13.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpmp00.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpmp01.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdpmp02.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdppmp00.tt-tim.tr:9092,rahdppmp01.tt-tim.tr:9092, rahdppmp02.tt-tim.tr:9092
 --partitions 2,1,0 --topic roc-parse-7485
```